# Unexpected behavior when browser request same page again with new tab

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, firefox

I have seen an unexpected behavior when i request my `test.php` with 2 tabs.

**Here is test.php script**

```
if (mkdir(/path/to/directory))
{
 sleep(10);
 rmdir(/path/to/directory);
 echo 'true';
}
 else
{
 echo 'false';
}
```

As you can see when i request page in first tab its running for 10 seconds sleep while this page running i request `test.php` again in another tab as expected it has to `echo false` but this request also running for 10 seconds sleep.

But when i'm doing first request in Chrome and second with Firefox it's working as expected.

I'm testing this with Chrome and Firefox.

Why browsers have this strange behavior?

Comment: have you tested `!is_dir(/path/to/directory) && mkdir(/path/to/directory)`

Comment: forget my last comment, is all about session & connections, if you use 2 browsers there 2 connections and different session if turned on. in another tab you get the same connection if not in any art of prviate mode.

Comment: I'm trying this after your comment everything is same.

Comment: Which kind of session ? Is you are talking about session_start()? or something else?

Comment: Yes. In different browsers you get diff. session ids

Comment: But i'm not staring any session yet my `test.php` script is as above nothing extra i added in this.

Comment: I was pointing to the connections ,too. Is basiclly not php, more a server thing.

Comment: Well, you can see exactly whether page was requested from server, or it was loaded from cache. Just open Developer Tools in chrome/firefox and switch to Network tab.

Comment: Ok can you explain something about connection or give me a link so i can understand this better?

Comment: just add `session_start();print sesssion_id();` and you will see, also check $_SERVER variable and lookup the browser header. sry cant find link and its kind of hart too explain for me.

Comment: @cronfy you are pointing me in right direction, When i'm doing requests with disable cache it's working as expected with same browser:) 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's ok @JOUM but as cronfy says it's cache issue I'm trying to disable cache and it's working as expected.
Thanks for your help .